# ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [^^^GFXO.AFN2] AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/psargs-330)

Tags: boot, 20.04, lenovo, ssd, acpi

[Every time I try to turn off/reboot my laptop, this logs appear to then turn off/reboot after some seconds.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O6a9.jpg)

I'm trying to look for a way of solving this and not only avoiding it as the "problem" seems to be coming from my SSD drive (nvme 0000:02:00.0).

I've seen people disabling acpi from their computers (adding `acpi=off` to their boot), but this justs avoids the error from showing. I would like to find a way of **solving it** and not just avoiding it.

**My system:**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Lenovo 330S-15IKB
- WD 500GB SSD (where ubuntu is located)
- 1000GB HDD
- Intel HD 620
- Intel Core I5-8250U

Thank you all for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272357/acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-sb-pci0-gp17-vga-lcd-bcm-afn